# How to use Azure DevOps with Kanban

Tags: kanban, azure-boards

I am reading Eric Brechener's [Agile Project Management with Kanban](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735698953) and Eric shows how to implement Kanban controlling tasks. He would breakdown topics into tasks and track the tasks in the board.

I want to use Kanban in Azure DevOps but the platform seems perfect for scrum though. I can only find on how to track work with Kanban if I only track Stories, I can't do Kanban as Eric shows in his book.

I guess I could make a fake Sprint that never finishes, so I could use the [Taskboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/task-board?view=azure-devops), but still this will be a hack.

**What's the best method for using Azure DevOps with Kanban? Is it ok to track only the Stories in the board?**

I am afraid that since stories vary in size a lot and take longer to finish, the Kanban process won't be as optimized as with Tasks. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

My concerns are the same as in [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/best-practices-kanban?view=azure-devops) Azure DevOps documentation:

> Variability of work in progress. Wide variability in the size of work items—users stories and bugs—can negatively influence the overall workflow. For example, items with estimates that vary in size from 4 hours to 14 days, or 2 to 55 story points, can't be counted the same when it comes to constraining work in progress.

Comment: I'm not familiarised with Azure DevOps, but there's plenty of free Kanban tools out there like Trello. Is there any reason you're locked in to use only Azure DevOps? Kanban is a tool for a goal and Azure DevOps is a tool for Kanban, so you may be wasting energy. Even a physical Kanban could work - what matters is what you want to visualise with the Kanban.

Comment: My company only uses Monday and Azure DevOps, and Moday lacks lots of features for Kanban. I think tracking stories will work, I am looking for "the best" workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to [Kanban in DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-quickstart?view=azure-devops)

As for your concern,  "items with estimates that vary in size from 4 hours to 14 days, or 2 to 55 story points". I think it would be better if we could sub-item i.e. create a separate user story rather than one big chunk else, the big user story could be taken as Epic and then divided into user stories.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look for a proper [Kanban System](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/kanban-system/) and either integrate or move compeltely to it. Otherwise it can be quite tedious to manage / achieve a proper Kanban process.